# Child bean is not found by the spring container

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I am facing an issue at runtime.
I have below spring bean definition and when I start the Tomcat server, "student" gets loaded but the child bean "address"
property is not getting injected(basically "address"  bean is not found I believe) and its value will be always null and thats why NPE thrown at runtime.
But if I use @Autowired annotation for "address" property instead of adding it in XML, it always works.

Could you please tell me why "address" is not found at runtime if I dont use @Autowired and what would be the fix so that container will find that bean
before loading "student"?

Note : Below defintions are in 2 different XMLs. Also, I logged the class names using verbose during startup and I see in both the cases (with and without @Autowired)
"com.test.Address" class is getting loaded and thats why I think in case of @Autowired , container is able to load that object by checking the type

```
<bean id="student" class="com.test.Student">
    <property name="address" ref="address" />
</bean>

<bean id="address" class="com.test.Address">
    <property name="street" value="Street1" />
    <property name="state" value="State1" />
    <property name="country" value="Country1" />
</bean>
```

**Class Definitions :**

```
public class Student {

private Address address;

    public setAddress(Address address) {
    this.address = address;
    }
}


public class Address {

private String street;
private String state;
private String country;

public setStreet(String street) {
    this.street = street;
    }
    
public setState(String state) {
    this.state = state;
    }
    
public setCountry(String country) {
    this.country = country;
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you please provide the source code of `com.test.Address` and `com.test.Student` ?

Comment: @MarkBramnik Added the class definitions

Comment: How are you loading the application context? If you use `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext ` it loads from xml and if you use `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext` or `ConfigurableApplicationContext` you can use `@Autowired`.

Answer (score 0):

You have put Address as a setter property of Student bean. So in Student class, you need to set Addreess, as below

```
public class Student {
    private Address address; // keep same name address as in bean
    public void setAddress(Address address) {
        this.address= address;
    }
}
```

After this, wherever, you use Student as @Autowired student, you will get address.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are not using `@Autowired` you have to load `applicationContext.xml`.

```
public class ExploreSpringXmlApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (ClassPathXmlApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml")) {
            Student s = applicationContext.getBean(Student.class)
```

But if you want to use `@Autowired` you can load the context using `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext`.

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
@ComponentScan({"the packages of your beans"})
public class ExploreSpringApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (AnnotationConfigApplicationContext applicationContext =
                     new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(ExploreSpringApplication.class)) {
```

Or if you are using spring boot: and want to use `@Autowired`:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan({"the packages of your beans"})
public class ExploreSpringBootApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext = 
SpringApplication.run(ExploreSpringBootApplication.class, args)) {
```

Answer (score 0):

The following example has worked for me (plain spring, without spring boot):

```
public class Student {
    private Address address;

    public void setAddress(Address address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
}

public class Address {
    private String street;
    private String state;
    private String country;

    public void setStreet(String street) {
        this.street = street;
    }

    public void setState(String state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }
}


public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ClassPathXmlApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/example/spring.xml");
        Student s = ctx.getBean(Student.class);
        System.out.println(s);
        ctx.close();
    }
}
```

Spring definitions xml (placed in `src/resources/example/spring.xml`):

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">
    <bean id="student" class = "example.Student">
        <property name="address" ref="address"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="address" class="example.Address">
        <property name="street" value="Street1" />
        <property name="state" value="State1" />
        <property name="country" value="Country1" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

So it looks like the mistake in configurations, maybe clash of spring jar versions, etc. - in short something that is not presented in the question.

Note that configuring the beans with XML is really outdated and real modern application should not really use this approach.